# Colloquial term for relationship between postdoc and phd with same advisor

Tags: phd, postdocs, terminology

Colloquially, two phds from the same advisor are referred to as academic brothers/sisters, i.e. if i am a phd student with advisor X and someone else is a phd student with advisor X then we are academic siblings. In this framework, how would one describe the relationship of a postdoc to a phd, both having the same advisor?

Comment: Why not just "colleagues"?

Comment: Of course one is always able to say colleagues, in fact it was even applicable to the case with two phd students sharing an advisor. However, it's not what I am asking; I want a term of endearment which fits into this familial framework. We could just say peers even, but it's not useful with respect to answering the question.

Comment: Such might exist in some languages/cultures, but I've never heard anything in English.

Comment: It's a very common colloquialism used to refer to two people who share an advisor for their phd. Such people are called academic siblings.

Comment: @TonyS.F. - not sure about ‘very common’ - I’ve only been a PhD for 30 years now and I really can’t recall having heard the term before in the US.

Comment: Nearly 50 for me and nothing rings a bell.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_genealogy
Common enough to warrant its own wikipedia entry, an entire page specifically for theoretical physics, and an entire database for mathematicians.


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_genealogy_of_theoretical_physicists

https://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/

Comment: My question for you: why it matters for you to call a colleague or peer or whatever as "academic sibling"? I mean, maybe I'm wrong, but It looks really weird. For example, if I want to talk to another student of my adviser: call him/her "academic sibling"?! For example: Hey "academic sibling", What's up today?! Come on, it's really weird... I prefer to call him/her with his first name or if our relationship is formal with his/her last name...

Comment: Yes, there are genealogy projects (I'm in one of them) but they don't really relate to your question.

Comment: @TonyS.F. - I knew the math folks were keen on connections, had not heard of the theoretical physics folks, but for those not in those disciplines, it is not very common at all. Yet again, Academia is not monolithic.

Comment: (This seems like a reasonable question to me. The term is also common in computer science.) But I don't know of any such terminology for postdocs.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer: You don't use it as a term of address; you wouldn't say things like "Hey, academic sibling, what's up" to their face.  But people do say things like "I'm working on a paper with Y; she's my academic aunt".

Comment: @NateEldredge Still, it looks weird... really "academic aunt"?! Maybe it's just weird for me cause I never heard it before...

Comment: The analogy between doctoral adviser and parent might be extended to an analogy between postdoc supervisor and step-parent, which would make the relationship you're asking about step-brother or step-sister. But I've never heard such an extension of the analogy, and I wouldn't advocate it beyond the comment that it seems less illogical than other options.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is any specific word for this.

In my experience, the "family" analogy (sibling, grandparent, uncle, etc) is only ever used for relationships defined in terms of the PhD advisor/student relationship.  I've never heard anything similar used for advisor/postdoc or any other type of academic relationship.

I think you just have to spell it out.  "He and I both worked with X; I was X's student and he was her postdoc."

Comment: Agreed, but note that [some people](https://www.utdallas.edu/news/2017/7/20-32576_Jindal-School-Celebrates-Retiring-Professors-42-Ye_story-wide.html) use terms like 'uncle' and 'cousin' term a bit loosely, seemingly more based on "interaction distance" than on a direct analogy with family trees.

Comment: Given how badly can end up the relationships between advisers and students, I suggest to tread _very_ carefully with such analogies.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano ...because family relationships never end that badly. (Cough.)